# AWS - EC2: Why would I need more than one instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Sorry if there is an obvious answer to this, but I'm currently in the process of setting up a new company, from where I'll be hosting client websites.  Rather than use an external hosting company, I'd like to take full control of this through EC2.

Can multiple websites be hosted on a single instance, or will each new site require it's own instance?

Many thanks,
L

Comment: This is not the forum to ask that, stackoverflow if for programming questions.

Answer (score 2):

Multiple websites can be hosted on one instance, given that the instance is large enough to handle all the traffic from all the different websites.

Here are two main reasons you would use more than one EC2 instance:

1. **Load**: A single instance would not be able to handle the load. In this case you would want to start up multiple servers and place them behind a load balancer so that the load can be shared across them. You might also want to split out each site into separate clusters of EC2 servers to further distribute the load.
2. **Fault tolerance**: If you don't design your system with the expectation that an EC2 instance can and will disappear at some point, then you will eventually have a very unpleasant surprise. With your site running on multiple servers, spread out across multiple availability zones, if a server or even an entire AZ goes down your site will stay up.

Comment: Thanks.  That' helped a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You don't say if each client will require the same code base or if each client will have a different site, but modularity is also important.

What happens if one client requires a different AMI. Say one client requires some special is package for the server. You don't want to keep updating everybody's app every time you have a new client requirement.

So, multiple instances will allow you to scale each customer at different times and rates and will allow you to develop each solution without affecting each other.

Pricing will also be cheaper as you can use auto scaling to be very efficient about CPU used at any given time, compared to a big instance where you will need to estimate future use.

In short, the biggest value of the cloud is elasticity and modularity, so use that in your favor.

Comment: Good points.  I'm learning a lot today :)

Comment: Feel free to upvote :-)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Mark B said in his answer about load and fault tolerance, having multiple instances allows you have them in different regions of the world.  This is helpful if you have requirements concerning the legality of where the data can be stored or more usually about the latency between the data and the user-application.  Data stored in an EU region is going to have much less latency for EU users than data stored in a NA region.